# Une explication de « châtier »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Je ne comprends pas encore comment les mots *châtiment* et *châtier* peuvent être utilisés. Je crains souvent de mal les employer. Je comprendrais mieux si on pouvait répondre aux questions suivantes :

- Tout d'abord, pensez-vous que ces mots peuvent détonner? Sont-ils un peu vieillis ou soutenus ?
- En second lieu, châtier quelqu'un, ça sert toujours à améliorer son propre comportement, ou ça peut aussi servir à débarrasser une personne encombrante ou nuisible? (Par exemple enfermer un malfaiteur pour que les autres gens soient hors de sa portée)
- J'ai lu qu'un châtiment est assez grave en comparaison avec ce que l'on appelle une punition. Pouvez-vous donner un exemple d'une peine qui « mérite » d'être qualifiée de châtiment?

Comment: J'ai hésité entre « pompeux » et « soutenu » pour rendre ton mot « boursouflé ». Tu verras celui que tu préfères, mais « boursouflé » n'est certainement pas ce que tu voulais dire, ici ça voudrait dire « creux, vide de sens ».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Châtier** vient du latin *castigare* (« essayer d'instruire ») lui-même dérivé de *castus* « chaste » (dans le sens de « conforme aux règles »).  **Châtier** c'était au départ réprimander dans un sens éducatif, on châtie pour rendre meilleur. Le mot fait aussi partie du vocabulaire chrétien : « se châtier » est synonyme de « se mortifier ».

**Punir** vient du latin *punire* qui voulait dire au départ « infliger un châtiment  ».

Donc les deux mots ont toujours eu des sens très proches, souvent employés indifféremment l'un pour l'autre, châtier étant beaucoup moins employé de nos jours et d'un niveau de langue beaucoup plus soutenu.
Cependant on emploiera châtier si on veut évoquer la valeur éducative : on  emploie châtier quand on a  l'espoir que la personne recevant le châtiment s'améliorera à travers la peine infligée, on châtie quelqu'un « pour son bien ». On parle aussi du « châtiment divin » pour une désigner une peine envoyée par Dieu.
Punir implique plus uniquement la peine infligée pour faute commise (matérielle ou morale) sans penser à l’amélioration morale de la personne. 
En terme juridique on parle de punition et non de châtiment.

À signaler l'emploi de l'adjectif « châtié » au sens figuré : en critique littéraire un « style châtié » est un style épuré, à la fois dépourvu de toutes fioritures et toujours très correct (ni familier, ni grossier, et correct grammaticalement).

Answer (score 1):

« Châtier / châtiment » ajoutent une notion de sévérité et souvent de souffrance infligée qui n'apparaît pas dans « punir/punition ».

« Châtier » ne s'emploie plus guère que dans le proverbe « Qui aime bien châtie bien ».

« Châtiment » est un peu plus courant, en particulier dans l'expression « châtiment corporel » qui décrit quelque chose d'effectivement beaucoup plus sévère qu'une punition "normale".

Comment: Châtier se retrouve très souvent dans la littérature classique.